# How to create a pop up window using php via echo?

Tags: php, popup

Is it possible to make a pop up window in my existing script?

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['success'] = ($result) ? TRUE : FALSE;

header('location: inv_fc.php');
```

---

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['success'] == TRUE) {
// CREATE POP UP WINDOW SUCCESS
} else {
// CREATE POP UP WINDOW FAILURE
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: take the time to learn/understand why you can replace `$_SESSION['success'] = ($result) ? TRUE : FALSE` with `$_SESSION['success'] = $result` or `$_SESSION['success'] = !!$result` depending on what $result can contain. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could open a pop-up using javascript or target a's attribute, but it's impossible from PHP, which is executed at server side.

Edit: ok, as I saw the `<script>` things: it's not PHP, it's Javascript, from PHP it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Javascript. For nicer results, use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

```
if ($_SESSION['success'] == TRUE) {
    echo "<script>alert('Success!');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Failure.');</script>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['success'] == TRUE)?>
  <script>window.open(...);alert('Your Awesome!');</script>
<?php else ?>
  <script>window.open(...);alert('You Fail!!');</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This will be caught by the standard popup blocking built into browsers. Windows can only be opened in response to a user-triggered event.